# ByRef argument type mismatch error raised when I change location of Dim statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim rangeStr, dataRow, bomRow, levelRow, sNewSheetName, quantRow As String
Dim y, desc, endcap As String
If SheetExists(sNewSheetName) Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sNewSheetName).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Private Function SheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim sSheet As Worksheet

    SheetExists = False
    For Each sSheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = sSheet.Name Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sSheet   
End Function
```

The error is raised on the third line in the If statement. I have a solution to my problem, but I want to understand why it works. The code is error free if I simply move the **quantRow** variable down to the 2nd dim statement so the first line ends with **sNewSheetName As String**. It seems adding a variable in front of **sNewSheetName** in the Dim statement makes this error appear and I'm curious to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the `Dim` Statement.

```
Dim blah, blah2, blah3 As String
```

Only `Blah3` is declared as String. The first two are Variants.

When you move the `quantRow` down, then the `sNewSheetName` is declared as `String` and it works fine. Before you move `quantRow`, `sNewSheetName` is declared as `Variant` and the subscript doesn't like it when you check for `SheetExists()` because it is expecting a `String` not a `Variant`.

```
Private Function SheetExists(sheetToFind As **String**) As Boolean
```

The correct way to `Dim` several items without declaring them as variants is:

```
Dim blah as String, blah2 as String, blah3 as String
```

Comment: This misunderstanding occurs quite often because in VB.NET `Dim blah, blah2, blah3 As String` declares all 3 as strings but in VBA it doesn't. One of the differences I hate most in VBA.

Comment: Yup, I did C# before I did VBA and I ran into the same misunderstanding.